# How in PyCharm can we quickly go to a folder recursively in Project View?

Tags: pycharm

From Project View in PyCharm, I want to go to an inner folder inside the folder tree by typing the folder name.

Currently it just works for folder in same level with current highlight tree node. I want it recursively searches in more inner level.

I'm using Pycharm 2016.3

[My google search](https://www.google.com.vn/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pycharm%20quickly%20go%20to%20a%20folder%20in%20project%20view) results little helpful on this.

Project View snapshot

[image]

Comment: I feel like this type of question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow and should be migrated to http://superuser.com/ instead, but I'm not voting to close because I'm not sure.

Comment: You will have to code by PyCharm as you work with Python and want to be good.